# How to get a specific category by index

Tags: categories, craft2

I have 4 level product categories. For the menu I am building I need to pick a second category in all top level categories

So I get top level categories like so

```
{% set lv1Categories  = craft.categories.group('products').level(1) %}
```

How do I then get a second in the returned list?

```
{% set cat = lv1Categories[1] %}
```

This doesn't seem to work

Comment: Hey, what do you expect `lv1Categories[1]` to do? Do you want a 2nd level subcategory?

Comment: Might help to post a screen cap of your category structure?

Comment: @Johannes There are two top level categories 'Recipients' and 'Departments'. 

I would expect lv1Categories[1] to reference 'Departments', so I can iterate over it's children with 

{% for categoryLv2 in categoryLv1.getChildren() %}

Comment: If that's your actual markup, then the first line is missing a `.all()` - without it, you have a CategoryQuery object rather than an iterable set of results.